# Enable and disable. One then the other

Tags: javascript, button

One button shows the user local time when clicked. Then I have another button that stops the clock.
I am trying to disable "show local time" when the button "stop time" is clicked.

`<button  id="start" onclick="showTime()" >Show Local showTime</button> <button  id="stop" onclick="myStop()">Stop Time</button>`

This is my code in HTML

I've tried this for my javascript
`document.getElementById(start).disabled = true; document.getElementById(stop).removeAttribute('disabled')`

Tried this

```
function showTime() {
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
  }
  
  function myStop() {
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
  }
```

None of these have works for disabling the other button. They both are being allowed to be clicked.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on the requirement? I got the point that you want to disable `show local time` when `stop time` is clicked. 
1.) Is that all? or do you need the reverse to work as well ( to disable `stop time` when `show local time` is clicked). 

2.) And after disabling `show local time` will it remain disabled forever, or do you need to enable it on the second click of `stop time`? or how you plan to enable the disabled button

Comment: Im trying to have stop time grayed out and unable to be clicked on when I click on show local time, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got the question, you need to disable one button when you click the other button. I will post an answer that will do the work.

```js
function showTime() {
    document.getElementById("stop").disabled = !document.getElementById("stop").disabled;
}
  
function myStop() {
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = !document.getElementById("start").disabled;

}
```

When you click the `show local time` button,

- it will disable the `stop time` if `stop time` is enabled
- it will enable the `stop time` if `stop time` is disabled

When you click the `stop time` button,

- it will disable the `show local time` if `show local time` is enabled
- it will enable the `show local time` if `show local time` is disabled

Comment: It does not work. Probably due to the fact I have a counter for the current time. `    my_pro = setTimeout(mySta, 1000);
` I added the code but doesn't do anything bc I'm already saying stop the current time from counting. Both buttons are still able to continue showing current time and the other stopping. Im trying to have stop time grayed out and unable to be clicked on when I click on show local time, and vice versa.